# dolphin "Find " not working

Tags: 16.04, search, find, dolphin

how do you get "find" to search for anything. when i type anything it says that it found nothing.

I've tried kde-baseapps, systemsettings , and kfind.

im using ubuntu 16.04 and the version of dolphin is  15.12.3

Comment: You ran a search for `kde-baseapps` in Dolphin? Like, you wanted to find where on the filesystem the package files are? Make sure you clicked the "Everywhere" button. In my case I'm not clicking "Everywhere", and am trying to find a file by its contents, recursively in the current dir. Doesn't work for me either - nothing's found.

Comment: I know exactly what he's asking.  Dolphin search does simply not work.  We need someone to help troubleshoot dolphin search.  Is it even working for anyone?